# Is there any difference between table and temporay table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

In SQL FIDDLE (sqlfiddle.com) I can build the schema for table:

```
create table test(name varchar2(20), id number);

insert into test values('posey', 363);
```

The following query runs and gives the correct result:

```
select * from test
/
```

I also try a temporary table, and I can build the schema.

```
create Global Temporary table test(name varchar2(20), id number);
insert into test values('posey', 363);
```

The following query runs but returns nothing.  Why does this happen?

```
select * from test
/
```

Comment: The clue is in the names.

Comment: Looks like some kind of SQLFiddle bug [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4cd14c/1)

Comment: Thank you lad2025.  From your demo I understand how to use the temp table and I agree with you this could be a SQLFiddle's bug.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tables in Oracle are either "transaction" or "session" specific; the former being the default. A transaction-specific temporary table will truncate itself after every `commit`. Presumably, the "Build Schema" section of SQL Fiddle includes a commit once it's complete, hence destroying the data.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

`Insert` and `select` have been made in the different sessions **or** insert into `global temporary table` have been commited (temporary table has `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` option by default).

Answer (score 0):

A temporary table is created within a session scope and the data exists only for that session.

The data in a global temporary table is private, such that data inserted by a session can only be accessed by that session. The session-specific rows in a global temporary table can be preserved for the whole session, or just for the current transaction.

From the docs [Creating a Temporary Table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400)

> The definition of a temporary table is visible to all sessions, but the data in a temporary table is visible only to the session that inserts the data into the table.

So when you create that session on the sqlfiddle (build schema) that session no longer exists therefore your select does not return any data.

Answer (score 0):

There are fundamental differences between these two objects on Oracle. Former is a physical table that allows you to store data for a given schema. Latter is a temporary object that allows you to store some data for the duration of your session.

If you include ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS clause as shown below, you will notice that your selected data will be kept in the GTT.

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE <table_name> (
 <column_name>  <column_data_type>,
 <column_name>  <column_data_type>,
 <column_name>  <column_data_type>)
 ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Run the INSERT in the "Run SQL" box, rather then the "Build
  Schema" box.
- Also, avoid committing after the insert, or add "ON
  COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS" to the CREATE command.